# gpg -a alternative

Tags: ascii

I want any tool (freeware) can convert any file to ascii output, like gpg -a.

the program should give me something like,

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.17 (MingW32)

jA0EAwMCxCbCmUr9TrG1ye1EJ3koyybtcdu6WuiYg0dL9UBWapeePCdw+/URfL4Z
UkxMtUjWb2PB4iBt2luEj8dYD5XzMIb6fOAo9nmnmYc8WwoPMq8F2aTmbUf/72Kg
nDOJZpK7M8mWf3uuCwCLiO+TCPAGWKTp5w40fj+CcJwNmGGabHDFuR6aiEEyj3Wg
6oFgBX/yzxJ5d6VUnfq9id830sLTSwaC/Zji2fYz53AMNMVPhfqINvLkaYO3Lqby
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

I google alot finding nothing, is there such a tool or no, I dont want the tool to ask for any passwords just convert file to ascii so I can send by email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GnuPG has this functionality as the **`--store`** option, which just wraps incoming data inside an OpenPGP "Literal Data" packet, which can be ASCII-armored. For decoding, use `gpg -d`. (There is also an `--enarmor` option, which adds no OpenPGP headers at all, just applies the "armor", and requires the corresponding `--dearmor` option to unwrap.)

However, the "ASCII armor" used in OpenPGP is just a modified version of **[Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)**, a very common algorithm for which many tools are available, many of them called just `base64` or `b64encode`, or `openssl base64 -e`.

However, all email clients that support MIME – that is, practically *every single email client* nowadays – **already have** built-in Base64 encoding functions. You just need to find the **"Attach file" option**, and the attachment will be automatically encoded when sending.

Another similar algorithm is [Uuencode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding), which is similar to Base64 but specific to mail & netnews, and rarely used elsewhere. See also [binary-to-text encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) for a general overview.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of base64 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)? That will convert a file into ascii characters that you can email and then reform into the file. There are numerous ways to convert a file to base64; http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/ is an example of an online tool.